# Make column values as column names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have this dataframe:

```
      mass        value
1 2390.421 0.0001376894
2 2390.713 0.0001362054
3 2391.004 0.0001346138
4 2391.296 0.0001329289
5 2391.588 0.0001311646
6 2391.879 0.0001293351
```

What I need is that the mass values becomes the column names:

```
   2390.421      2390.713       2391.004  ..... 
0.0001376894   0.0001362054   0.0001346138 .....
```

I tried reshape, unstack, do.call, but I still couldn't do it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = a, values_from = b)

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  `2390.421` `2390.713` `2391.004` `2391.296` `2391.588` `2391.879`
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1   0.000138   0.000136   0.000135   0.000133   0.000131   0.000129
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `transpose` from `data.table`

```
data.table::transpose(df1, make.names = 'mass')
#    2390.421     2390.713     2391.004     2391.296     2391.588     2391.879
#1 0.0001376894 0.0001362054 0.0001346138 0.0001329289 0.0001311646 0.0001293351
```

---

Or with `deframe/as_tibble_row`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
deframe(df1) %>%
   as_tibble_row
# A tibble: 1 x 6
#  `2390.421` `2390.713` `2391.004` `2391.296` `2391.588` `2391.879`
#       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1   0.000138   0.000136   0.000135   0.000133   0.000131   0.000129
```

---

Or using `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(value ~ mass, df1)
#mass
#    2390.421     2390.713     2391.004     2391.296     2391.588     2391.879 
#0.0001376894 0.0001362054 0.0001346138 0.0001329289 0.0001311646 0.0001293351
```

It is a `matrix`, but can be converted to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame.list(xtabs(value ~ mass, df1) , check.names = FALSE)
#   2390.421     2390.713     2391.004     2391.296     2391.588     2391.879
#1 0.0001376894 0.0001362054 0.0001346138 0.0001329289 0.0001311646 0.0001293351
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(mass = c(2390.421, 2390.713, 2391.004, 2391.296, 
2391.588, 2391.879), value = c(0.0001376894, 0.0001362054, 0.0001346138, 
0.0001329289, 0.0001311646, 0.0001293351)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
> t(unstack(rev(df)))
        2390.421     2390.713     2391.004     2391.296     2391.588
res 0.0001376894 0.0001362054 0.0001346138 0.0001329289 0.0001311646
        2391.879
res 0.0001293351
```

or a `data.table` option

```
> dcast(setDT(df), . ~ mass, value = "value")[, -1]
       2390.421     2390.713     2391.004     2391.296     2391.588
1: 0.0001376894 0.0001362054 0.0001346138 0.0001329289 0.0001311646
       2391.879
1: 0.0001293351
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(mass = c(2390.421, 2390.713, 2391.004, 2391.296,
2391.588, 2391.879), value = c(0.0001376894, 0.0001362054, 0.0001346138,
0.0001329289, 0.0001311646, 0.0001293351)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```